# Display content like in Medium app

Tags: android

I need to create news app with blog posts that should contain images, videos and formatted text like in the Android Medium app. I will attach screenshots below. It seems like there is a `WebView` in full height of its content inside `RecyclerView` or `ScrollView` with the native elements in the end. How to develop a similar view in the right way? 
[image: Screenshot#1][image: Screenshot#2][image: Screenshot#3][image: Screenshot#4]

Comment: While obviously we can't tell you exactly how to make this, one start could be going into Android Studio and performing a layout inspection (Tools > Android > Layout Inspector). This will show you what the layout consist of, then you can start asking targeted questions. Like how to use a recyclerview or implement a webview inside of a recyclerview.

Comment: @TimKranen How can I use layout inspector on a not debug build?